# Checking if a subdirectory exists using glob in script

Tags: shell-script, zsh, directory, wildcards

I'm trying to check if a directory `bin` is inside a directory which can sometimes change. In this particular case, the version number of ruby can change (e.g. `$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin`). Here's what I did so far:

```zsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
ruby_gem_home="$HOME/.gem/ruby/*/bin"
if [[ -d $ruby_gem_home ]]; then
  echo "The ruby gems directory exists!"
else
  echo "Ruby gems directory missing!"
fi
```

I don't want to use `find` as this is part of a login process. What's the most elegant way, using built-in zsh/bash commands, to achieve this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention this is for a `zsh` script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an array, and check whether the first element (i.e. [0] in bash, [1] in zsh) of the array is a directory.  e.g. in `bash`:

```bsh
# the trailing slash in "$HOME"/.gem/ruby/*/bin/ ensures that
# the glob matches only directories.
rubygemdirs=( "$HOME"/.gem/ruby/*/bin/ )

if [ -d "${rubygemdirs[0]}" ] ; then
   echo "At least one ruby gem dir exists"
else
   echo "No ruby gem dirs were found"
fi
```

To work in both `zsh` and `bash`, you need to first find out which shell is currently running.  That will tell you whether the first index of an array is `0` or `1`.
It will also determine whether you need to use `(N)` with the glob to tell zsh NOT to exit if there are no matches for the glob (zsh will exit by default on glob matching errors).

(at this point, it should be starting to become obvious that writing a script to work reliably in **both** bash and zsh is probably going to be more trouble than it's worth)

```bsh
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] ; then
   first_idx=0
   rubygemdirs=( "$HOME"/.gem/ruby/*/bin/ )
elif [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION"  ] ; then
   first_idx=1
   emulate sh
   rubygemdirs=( "$HOME"/.gem/ruby/*/bin/ )
   emulate zsh
fi

if [ -d "${rubygemdirs[$first_idx]}" ] ; then
...
```

If required, you can also iterate over the array to check whether an element matches a particular version.  e.g.

```bsh
for d in "${rubygemdirs[@]}" ; do
  [[ $d =~ /2\.6\.0/ ]] && echo found gem dir for ruby 2.6.0
done
```

Note: the `/`s in the regex are literal forward-slashes.  They don't mark the beginning and end of the regex as in `sed`.

Comment: Tried this in `zsh` but can't get it to work :( `No ruby gem dirs were found`
```

Comment: try testing for `${rubygemdirs[1]}` instead of [0].

Comment: Yup! using `rubygemdirs[1]` worked! Adding a flag to determine the shell is really dope. Awesome solution! Thanks!

Comment: `bash` and `zsh` have significantly different syntax and features, as well as some more subtle differences (like array indices).   Only really simple (or very carefully written) scripts will work reliably in both.   Most of the time, you'd be better off writing two scripts (one for bash, one for zsh) and a wrapper script to execute (or source) one or the other of them.

Comment: @FrancisV why not add a shebang and set the script yourself?

Comment: This doesn't work in zsh (unless some options have changed from the default): non-matching globs result in an error.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - it still works, it just prints an error message to stderr.   It's safe enough in this context to just redirect that to /dev/null because the only thing we care about is whether it found a matching directory or not. An error (and resulting empty array) gives us that answer ("No").

Comment: No, by default, the error causes zsh to exit if it isn't interactive.

Comment: `set -e` by default?   yet another reason i'm glad i don't use zsh.

Comment: `[[ $d =~ /2\.6\.0/ ]]` is the same as `[[ $d =~ /2.6.0/ ]]` in zsh (like in bash 3.1 but not in 3.2+ unless `compat31` is on), so it matches on `foo/2x6x0/bar` for instance. You'd want `[[ $d = */2.6.0/* ]]` to match on anything that contains `/2.6.0/` or `[[ $d =~ '/2\.6\.0/' ]]` if you really need to use a regexp. To check whether the array contain at least one element matching the pattern, it's just `if (( ${rubygemdirs[(I)*/2.6.0/*]} ))..` though.

Comment: About the difficulty of writing a script compatible with both Bash and Zsh... Bash croaks on that `rubygemdirs=( "$HOME"/.gem/ruby/*/bin/(N) ) 2>/dev/null`, even if it's on the non-executed branch of the `if`. It still has to parse it. You'd need to protect it somehow, e.g. hiding the whole line in `eval '...'`. (Also in Bash, `nullglob` could be used.)

Comment: @ilkkachu yep. more trouble than it's worth.  a lot more trouble.    latest attempt uses zsh's `emulate` built-in, bash should have no reason to complain about that.   basic testing indicates that the same script works whether run with bash or zsh.

Comment: @cas, yep, that works too.

Comment: it just keeps getting uglier and uglier.  at least i tested in a script this time, last time I just tested from the command line, and zsh doesn't exit when globs don't match in that context (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 8):

#### For this case specifically

I don't think it makes sense to look for any directory. What's the point of using a directory that doesn't match the installed version of Ruby? And what if the user has configured a different directory in `~/.gemrc`?

I'm not very familiar with Ruby, but I think the correct solution is to take the first entry in `gempath`.

```
ruby_gem_home=$(gem environment gempath | sed 's/:.*//')
if [ -z "$ruby_gem_home" ]; then unset ruby_gem_home; fi
```

#### In zsh

```
function set_ruby_gem_home {
  emulate -LR zsh
  local dirs
  dirs=($HOME/.gem/ruby/*/bin(NnOn))
  if (($#dirs == 0)); then
    unset ruby_gem_home
  else
    ruby_gem_home=$dirs[0]
  fi
}
```

The [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `N` ensures that the result is an empty array rather than an error if there is no match. The glob qualifiers `n` and `On` sort the list by decreasing version numbers; tweak this to pick a different item when there are multiple matches.

In bash:

```
function set_ruby_gem_home {
  local dirs
  dirs=(~/.gem/ruby/*/bin(NnOn))
  if (($#dirs == 0)); then
    unset ruby_gem_home
  else
    ruby_gem_home=$dirs[0]
  fi
}
```

#### In bash

```
function set_ruby_gem_home {
  local dirs restore_options
  restore_options=$(setopt +o)
  shopt -s nullglob
  dirs=(~/.gem/ruby/*/bin)
  if (($#dirs == 0)); then
    unset ruby_gem_home
  else
    ruby_gem_home=${dirs[${#dirs[@]}-1]}
  fi
  eval "$restore_options"
}
```

Here I take the last array element, which is often but not always the most recent version: `10` is sorted before `9`.

Answer (score 4):

Wildcards are only expanded in list contexts, that is, where they can be expanded to several things. In an assignment to scalar variable, they can't be expanded as a scalar variable can only hold one value.

With `ruby_gem_home="$HOME/.gem/ruby/*/bin"`, you'd just be storing the `/home/user/.gem/ruby/*/bin` string into `$ruby_gem_home` scalar variable, not the list of files that glob would expand to if in list context.

List contexts in zsh can be arguments to simple commands or anonymous functions, after `for/select x in`, in the targets of redirections (when `multios` is on), in array or associative array assignments and a few other corner cases¹.

So, here, you could use an anonymous function:

```
() {
  unset ruby_gem_home
  case $# in
    (0) print -u2 "Ruby gems directory missing!";;
    (1) print -u2 "The ruby gems directory exists!"
        ruby_gem_home=$1;;
    (*) print -u2 "More than one ruby gem directory, don't know which to choose!";;
  esac
} ~/.gem/ruby/*/bin(N-/)
```

Here also adding the `N` glob qualifier so that the glob expands to an empty list when there's no match instead of reporting an error, and `-/` to restrict to files of type *directory* (determined after symlink resolution with `-`).

If there's more than one ruby gem dir and you want to pick the one with the highest version number, you can do:

```
() {
  unset ruby_gem_home
  case $# in
    (0) print -u2 "Ruby gems directory missing!";;
    (1) print -u2 "The ruby gems directory exists!"
        ruby_gem_home=$1;;
    (*) print -ru2 "More than one ruby gem directory, picking $1!"
        ruby_gem_home=$1;;
  esac
} ~/.gem/ruby/*/bin(N-/nOn)
```

Where `n` turns on `numericglobsort`, and `On` `o`rders in reverse by `n`ame, so `$1` will contain the one with the highest number.

---

<sup>¹ As explained in [`info zsh 'Conditional Expressions'`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions), there's also a special case when the `extendedglob` option is on in which case you can use use globs inside `[[ ... ]]`, typically with the `-n`/`-z` operators. So you could use `[[ -n ~/.gem/ruby/*/bin(#qN-/) ]]` to check whether there is at least one such directory here.</sup>